# Gaussian plots with filter plots using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to get these plots:

[image]

and

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
  axis lines*=left, xlabel=$score$, ylabel=$freq$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=12cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major
  ]
  \addplot [fill=blue!50,very thick,cyan!40!black] {gauss(6.5,1)} \closedcycle;

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like some help to add the annotations and 2nd curves on each plots.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: One way is to use \pgfplotsextra.  Another is to define named coordinates inside the axis environment, but not use them until after \end{axis}.  Also (rel axis cs: x,y) coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `node` for the labels and drawing and `scope` for the second plot:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
  axis lines=left, xlabel=$score$, ylabel=$freq$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=12cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major
  ]
  \addplot [fill=blue!50,very thick,cyan!40!black] {gauss(6.5,1)} \closedcycle;
  \node[align=center,anchor=south] at (axis cs: 6.5, 0.4){client\\scores};
  \node[align=center,anchor=north] at (axis cs: 6.5, 0){client\\mean};
  \draw[dashed] (axis cs: 6.5, 0.4) -- (axis cs: 6.5, 0);
\end{axis}

\begin{scope}[xshift=15cm]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,height=5cm, width=12cm,]
  \addplot coordinates{(0,0)(1,1)}; % dummy plot
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may wanna use a function to calculate the density at the mean value rather than the hard coded 0.4 I used.